# Label encoding ordinal and integers for scikit-learn

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn

I have different kinds of columns to encode: (a) nominal values (strings), (b) ordinal values (strings) and (c) ordinal values (numerical) which were manually mapped (using map) from qualifications such as 'Excellent', 'Poor', etc since there was no alphabetical order to properly assign values.

Knowing that the output of LabelEncoder is a column of integers, should I LabelEncode group b and also group c or only group b? Here I provide examples of all groups.

Group a (OneHotEncoding)

```
GarageType: Garage location

       2Types   More than one type of garage
       Attchd   Attached to home
       Basment  Basement Garage
       BuiltIn  Built-In (Garage part of house - typically has room above garage)
       CarPort  Car Port
       Detchd   Detached from home
       NA   No Garage
```

Group b (LabelEncoding)

```
GarageFinish: Interior finish of the garage

       Fin  Finished
       RFn  Rough Finished  
       Unf  Unfinished
       NA   No Garage
```

Group c (mapped)

```
GarageQual: Garage quality

       Ex   Excellent
       Gd   Good
       TA   Typical/Average
       Fa   Fair
       Po   Poor
       NA   No Garage
```

I'm getting the values of group C correctly map, my question is I have to apply LabelEncoder even if they are integers.

Comment: Well, I would argue that your group c is not totally ordinal, is it, given that there is the field "no garage", which cannot be ordered relatively to the other fields such as "excellent" or "poor"

Comment: I agree with that. In that sense should I treat it as nominal for OneHotEncoding? I would think that the information given by the ordinal values (excluding "no garage") might be valuable.

Comment: Because, what I am doing right now with group C "no garage" values is mapping them to zero and the others from 1 to 5.

Comment: What you could do is map this variable like you said and add a dummy variable that would encode whether or not there is a garage. Might be the best compromise.